# Django | REST | Add of top level JSON field breaks filtering option

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have to work ListAPIView view, via which I can filter via django-filter values. But I need to add an object in JSON (because AMP HTML needs that) and when I add this, It will break this filtering.

When I use this view, filtering is works great:

```
class TypeAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    queryset = Type.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TypeSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('code', )


    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But when I want to add a top level JSON object, it will breaks a filtering option:

```
class TypeAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny, )
    queryset = Type.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TypeSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ('code', )


def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    # --- modified from here ---
    custom_data = {
        'vehicles': serializer.data
    }
    return Response(custom_data)
    # --- END modified from here ---
```

Is possible to add a top-level JSON object and keep the filtering of django-filter working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is taken from django source code:

```py
class ListModelMixin:
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Try to use this format and add the tracklog from your terminal.

Comment: This work well ... it returns: [{"pk":1,"code":"V","model_set":["Camry","Focus","Rav4","Cobalt","Impala"]}] - when I print(serializer.data) it returns [OrderedDict([('pk', 1), ('code', 'V'), ('model_set', ['Camry', 'Focus', 'Rav4', 'Cobalt', 'Impala'])])]
But I need this format: {"vehicles":[{"pk":1,"code":"V","model_set":["Camry","Focus","Rav4","Cobalt","Impala"]}]} - print {'vehicles': [OrderedDict([('pk', 1), ('code', 'V'), ('model_set', ['Camry', 'Focus', 'Rav4', 'Cobalt', 'Impala'])])]}
and it is again broken, when I use custom_data = {vehicles': serializer.data } and return as Response

Comment: could you add the bug trace please

Comment: Console is not returning any trace - only GET requests. Or is there any way, how to neable better tracking? [01/Dec/2020 18:46:40] "GET /api/type/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5564
[01/Dec/2020 18:46:40] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[01/Dec/2020 18:46:40] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/ajax-form.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[01/Dec/2020 18:46:40] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/prettify-min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[01/Dec/2020 18:46:40] "GET /static/rest_framework/js/default.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Comment: It returns all data correctly, but when I use custom_data = {'vehicles': serializer.data} and return it as Response, it disables Filter option

Comment: Sorry for that, it works! Thank you! Dont know why, it only disables a button, but when I add a filter in url: /api/type/?code=V it works ...